# Галерея на WP по типу "карточки товара" без подключения WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я делаю блог на WP. Мне нужно сделать страницу с товарами, которые размещаются просто для ознакомления - без корзины и т.п. Кликаешь на изображение - всплывает окно с информацией (увеличенное изображение, цена, характеристики, размер и т.п.).

Как это сделать, не подключая woocommerce?

Если можно, то какую галерею посоветуете.

Ну и в целом, как новичок, приму любые советы по решению этой задачи. Благодарю.

Comment: В целом подключите woocommerce и не изобретайте велосипед. Потом, когда клиент захочет корзину, у вас уже все под рукой.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я так и сделала. 

И дополню, может кому пригодится: чтобы не было кнопки "добавить в корзину" - просто не нужно указывать цену при заполнении карточки товара. 

Ну и через редактор страниц убрала лишние "магазинные" страницы.

Comment: Все правильно. Я так и делал несколько "каталожных" сайтов на WooCommerce.